# Having multiple processes/threads running at all times, accessing a sqlite3 db until a condition is met

Tags: python, multithreading, process, sqlite, multiprocessing

Bear with me - this is my first mulit-threading/processing python project.

I'm working on a python script which is supposed to run *n* instances of *some.exe* where each requires an ID as a parameter. The IDs are fetched from a local sqlite database and are deleted if processed successfully. No ID should ever be processed by more than one *some.exe* at a time (thus the WORK *boolean*).

I'm aware that the `pool.map` below requires an *iter* of some kind but as this is my very first project including any form of mulit-threading/processing, I do not know how else to handle it.

The script is supposed to run until no IDs are left - constantly running *n* instances of *some.exe*. *some.exe* will probably take 1-6 minutes for each ID.

If releveant, this will run on a windows machine.

The code is partially just pseudo-code and all non-essential parts have been omitted:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time, sqlite3
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool   

def run_worker(lite_cur):

    lite_cur.execute("SELECET ID FROM IDS WHERE WORK != 1")
    found_id = lite_cur.fetchone()

    lite_cur.execute("UPDATE IDS SET WORK = 1 WHERE ID = \'"+found_id+"\'")

    #starting a subprocess in a pool is probably not what one should do.. help?
    process = subprocess.Popen(["some.exe", found_id])
    process.wait()

    #how would one check if some.exe chrashed or completed successfully?
    if process = "some.exe completed without errors!":
        lite_cur.execute("DELETE FROM IDS WHERE ID = \'"+found_id+"\'")
    else:
        #do this if some.exe crashed or reported errors.
        lite_cur.execute("UPDATE IDS SET WORK = 0 WHERE ID = \'"+found_id+"\'")


def run_checker(lite_cur, ids_left):
    time.sleep(600)
    lite_cur.execute("SELECT * FROM IDS")
    #may exceed 1 million, is there a better/faster way?
    if len(lite_cur.fetchall()) == 0:
        ids_left = False

def main():

    #lite_db_name will be implemented as an argument.
    lite_db_name = "some.db"
    lite_con = sqlite3.connect(lite_db_name)
    lite_cur = lite_con.cursor()

    #IDs should be self-explanatory and WORK is used as a boolean to define if a worker is already working on this ID 
    lite_cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS IDS(ID TEXT, WORK INTEGER DEFAULT 0)")

    #max_worker will be implemented as an argument
    max_worker = 4
    worker_pool = Pool(max_worker)
    #a pool with the limit of 1 is probably dumb as duck.. 
    checker_pool = Pool(1)

    lite_cur.execute("SELECT * FROM IDS")
    if len(lite_cur.fetchall()) > 0:
        ids_left = True
    else:
        ids_left = False

    while ids_left:
        worker_pool.map(run_worker(lite_cur))
        checker_pool.map(run_checker(lite_cur, ids_left))

    end_time = datetime.now()
    print ("Congratulation - All IDs processed.")
    print ("It took: {}".format(end_time - start_time))

if  __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'd be most grateful for any suggestions and comments.

edit: sorry for not posting an explicit question. This *questions* intention was to get some leading suggestions for any further development.

Comment: Could you clarify what the specific question is please?

Comment: There's no explicit question to a concrete problem. I guess you expect some kind of "howto". That's difficult, even more if your introduction barely matches the source. There's not even a single sentence ending in a question mark. I guess it's because you yourself are unsure if you even have a problem. There's no absolute "right" way. Tackle your problem in a way you can still understand your source/solution in a year.

Comment: @DonQuestion You're right. I'm not asking for a specific answer, nor a how-to. I'm asking you to lead me to the *right* direction, or give me some hints how I could accomplish the remaining pseudo-code parts. I was worried that the *question* wouldn't be very popular, but I asked anyway as I often got help from a comment or an answert which gave me a direction leading hint.

Comment: avoid threading; using `subprocess.Popen(cmd).poll()` gives you enough parallelization. Save the running proccesses in a dict (with a max-len of e.g. 20 -> max concurrently running proccesses) and check in a loop if they are finished. Remove every finished process from the dict and fill the space with a new process/id.

Comment: @DonQuestion thank you very much for the suggestion! Wouldn't the checking be quite cpu intensive? For instance when I pseudo-code something like `while not the_end: for subproc in dict: if not subproc.isrunning(): start_new_subproc(current_dict_space)`

Comment: true, polling adds overhead, but this can easily reduced with a little forced sleep-period. i added an examplary code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exemplary code (functional, tested):

```
import sqlite3 as sql
from this import s as nonsense
import subprocess
import shlex
import time

max_parallel_processes = 10

def getdb(tableid = "test"):
    dbid = ":memory:"    

    stmt_create = "CREATE TABLE %s (id int, comment text)" % tableid
    stmt_insert = "INSERT INTO %s VALUES (?, ?)" % tableid

    values = enumerate(nonsense.split())

    db = sql.connect(dbid)
    db.execute(stmt_create)
    db.executemany(stmt_insert, values)
    return db


def get_ids(db, tableid = "test"):
    stmt_select_id = "SELECT id from %s " % tableid
    crs = db.execute(stmt_select_id)
    result = crs.fetchall()
    for i in result:
        yield i


def main():
    from random import randint

    db = getdb()
    process_lst = {}    
    sleep_between_polls_in_seconds = 0.1

    for rowid in get_ids(db):
        if len(process_lst) < max_parallel_processes:
            cmd_str = "sleep %s"  % randint(1, 3)
            cmd = shlex.split(cmd_str)

            print "adding : %s (%s)" % (rowid, cmd_str)

            proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)    
            process_lst[proc] = rowid
            proc.poll()
        else:
            print "max processes (%s) reached" % max_parallel_processes

            for proc in process_lst.keys():
                finished = proc.poll() is not None           
                if finished:
                    print "%s finished" % process_lst[proc]
                    del process_lst[proc]

                time.sleep(sleep_between_polls_in_seconds)

    print "All processes processed: %s "  %(len (process_lst) == 0)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In my example i did no testing of the output (stderr, stdout) of the invoked subprocesses, which your code seems to must do, but this is easily achieved through the Popen-constructor.
Furthermore redirecting the stdout/stderr may allow to replace the `time.sleep` pausing of the polling loop with a `select`-construct (at least under *nix-environments).

This way you achieve parallelization, by avoiding dreadful threading. Keep in mind that both `subprocess.Popen` and `threading.Thread` spawn their own process. That's quite the overhead to wrap a subprocess-process addintionally into a threading-process, with no gained functionality. You still have to establish a queue-like structure.

Hope that helps.

**edit**:
`proc.poll()` is needed for two reasons:

1. to start the external process
2. to let it run in the background (non-blocking)

Adding `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to Popen allows the reading of the std-output file `Popen().stdout` in my example:

```
with proc.stdout as f:
    program_output = f.read()
```

Comment: thank you very much - explained and helped a lot and pretty much brought me to my *slightly adpated* solution!

Comment: There's a little caveat hidden in my solution, i hope you realized. I just test if the "process-list/queue" is completely full, but at the end you must additionally check if it's also completely empty, else the last 10 processes may never be checked!

Comment: Why do I need the `proc.poll()` in `if len(process_lst) < max_parallel_processes:`?